# Using Tailwind CSS, in a React input how do I truncate the text early while keeping the input container the same size?

Tags: css, reactjs, forms, input, tailwind-css

I'm using Tailwind CSS, and I have this React input component:

```
<input
  type="text"
  id="username"
  name="username"
  className="rounded-md ml-3 pl-1 outline-0"
/>
```

If I fill it up with text so that it overflows, it looks like this when the cursor is at the end of the text:
[screenshot of input container without the extra padding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zsVU.png)

However, I want the text to instead be truncated early so that there is always some white space on the right-hand side of the inside of the input container.

I was able to accomplish my goal by adding pr-6 to the input like this:

```
<input
  type="text"
  id="username"
  name="username"
  className="rounded-md ml-3 pl-1 outline-0 pr-6"
/>
```

But unfortunately this also added width to the entire input container on the left-hand side:
[screenshot of input container with the extra padding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwwIG.png)

I tried setting the width explicitly, but I got a funny result where the width suddenly "jumps" at a certain point. This is what I got with `className="rounded-md ml-3 pl-1 outline-0 pr-6 w-24"`:
[screenshot of input container with w-24 added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wlsc.png)

And this is what I got with `className="rounded-md ml-3 pl-1 outline-0 pr-6 w-25"`:
[screenshot of input container with w-25 added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heQtw.png)

How I can get that early text truncation and have the right-hand side of the textbox behave as above, but without the extra space added to the left-hand side? I'd prefer a solution that can be accomplished without additional packages.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
<input
  type="text"
  id="username"
  name="username"
  class="whitespace-nowrap overflow-hidden text-ellipsis w-40"
/>
```

And it will look like this
[image]

Comment: I tried your solution in my code, but it didn't have any effect. I changed your `w-40` to `w-50` to match my design, so this is what I used: `className="rounded-md ml-3 pl-1 outline-0 whitespace-nowrap overflow-hidden text-ellipsis w-50"`. But it still looked the exact same as the first image from my post [https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zsVU.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zsVU.png). There were no ellipses and no truncation, unfortunately.

Comment: I tried your solution on [https://play.tailwindcss.com](https://play.tailwindcss.com), as well, but it didn't work there either.

Comment: This is my bad, I think it should be just "class" and not "className"

I tried it and it works. 
https://play.tailwindcss.com/bgHUGI2YPn

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't the solution I need. As stated in my question, I'm need to add blank space on the right-hand side of the container. Having ellipses there doesn't solve this, which I should have said in my previous comments. Instead, I'm looking for a solution which accomplishes the second photo in my post (without the added width): [https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwwIG.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwwIG.png). You can see that there's more overflow text to the left, but there's a fixed space between the right-hand side of the container and the end of the text line on the right-hand side.